# AngularJs Attribute Directive 2 Way Binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app like this

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wjbb5o00EUj6ShaYlgXv)

Javascript:

```
(function(angular, module){

    module.controller("TestController", function($scope){
        $scope.magicValue = 1;
    });

    module.directive("valueDisplay", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            template: '<span>Iso Val: </span>{{ value }}<br/><span>Iso Change: </span><input data-ng-model="value" />',
            replace: false,
            scope: { },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var pValKey = attrs.valueDisplay;

                // Copy value from parent Scope.
                scope.value = scope.$parent[pValKey];

                scope.$parent.$watch(pValKey, function(newValue) {
                    if(angular.equals(newValue, scope.value)) {
                        // Values are the same take no action
                        return;
                    }
                    // Update Local Value
                    scope.value = newValue;
                });

                scope.$watch('value', function(newValue) {
                    if(angular.equals(newValue, scope.$parent[pValKey])) {
                        // Values are the same take no action
                        return;
                    }
                    // Update Parent Value
                    scope.$parent[pValKey] = newValue;
                });
            }
        };
    });

}(angular, angular.module("Test", [])));
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc2" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="Test">
        <div ng-controller="TestController">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <span>Parent Val: </span>{{ magicValue }}<br/>
                    <span>Parent Change:</span><input data-ng-model="magicValue" />
                </li>
                <li data-value-display="magicValue"></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ok so This works and all but I'm wondering if there is not a better way of doing this 2 way binding that I have setup here?

Keep in mind that I want Isolated Scope & that I know I can define extra Attributes and use the '=' to have 2 way data binding between parent and isolated scope I'd like something like that but where the data gets passed in to the directives attribute like I have here.

Comment: What is stopping you from using scope : {valueDisplay : '=valueDisplay'}? you don't have to set up the watches and the value is still in an attribute. It's also brittle to use $parent, since you can never be sure that the value is actually set in the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this much more tersely using your isolated scope.

Here is an updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ee5hAS9h7DEpXY9JftaX?p=preview).

You can two-way bind the value of your directive with `value: '=valueDisplay'`

The `=` tells angular you want two-way binding:

```
module.directive("valueDisplay", function () {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      template: '<span>Iso Val: </span>{{ value }}<br/><span>Iso Change: </span><input data-ng-model="value" />',
      replace: false,
      scope: { value: '=valueDisplay' },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Was in the middle of writing the same thing, but you nailed it.  The OP really just wrote what Angular does for you.